# How to update the Color of Button from another class/ by passing it in a function in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I want to Change the Color of button on a specific Condition by another class/by passing the button in a function.. I have the code of Winform but I need it for WPF..
Here is Winform application Code

```
internal static void BtnOnOff(Button button1, byte v)
{
    if (v == 1)
    {
        button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen; // What for WPF ?
    }
    else
    {
        button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have to change brushes. Try this:

```
internal static void BtnOnOff(Button button1, byte v){
 if (v==1)
 {
 button1.Background= System.Windows.Media.Brushes.YellowGreen;
 }
 else
 {
 button1.Background= System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlBrush;
 }
}
```

Comment: It Works.. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming `BackColor` u mean `Background` prop

`button1.Background = Brushes.YellowGreen`

Comment: Yes it is applicable when updating color within a class which is related to the XAML.. but cannot apply this method in another class

Comment: if ur using it from a normal class `Brushes` will use the `System.Drawing`  namespace but for a `button.Background` prop uses `Brushes` from `System.Windows.Media` namespace the question is not about namespaces

Comment: Absolutely .. Thanks